# Can a Global Apex class be exposed in a managed package as a valid Lightning Attribute Type?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I've exposed a global Apex class `Totaller` (for example), and I'm able to use it within my development environment as a Lightning attribute.

```
global class Totaller {
    @AuraEnabled global Integer num1;
    @AuraEnabled global Integer num2;
    @AuraEnabled global Integer total;
}
```

Within my components in my packaging environments, I can use:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="updateData" type="c:dataUpdate"/>
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Totaller"/>
</aura:component>
```

When I release this package, I'd like others to be able to use this data structure as well. Based on the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm), I believe my Subscriber should be able to use it in their own component like this:

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:registerEvent name="updateData" type="packagenamespace:dataUpdate"/>
  <aura:attribute name="data" type="packagenamespace.Totaller"/>
</aura:component>
```

But trying to save this file from an org with this component installed, I get the error, `Failed to save MyComponent.cmp: Invalid <aura:attribute> type: Totaller: Source`. The event is accessed fine. I'm also able to access `packagenamespace.Totaller` through regular Apex code.

Either I'm missing something silly, or it's not supported. Has anyone done this?

Thanks!

Comment: You dont have to keep its type as "packagenamespace.Totaller", if you keep it as Object, it will still get the job done.